# Message box shows before all data insert in iot hub c#

Tags: c#, messagebox, azure-iot-hub

I have CSV file. I read that CSV file and that csv file data converts to json then that json will upload in Iot hub.

That CSV file may contains 1400 to 5000 records. After inserting all records I will show the message like **Data inserted successfully**

Here when one single row got inserted that message showing popup. It's did not wait for all records getting insert.

```
  private async Task DataSendstoAzureIotHub(string jsonserv, string deviceID)
    {

        DeviceClient s_deviceClient;
        Console.WriteLine("upload time start" + DateTime.Now);
        try
        {
            if (registryManager == null)
            {
                registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(s_connectionString01);
            }
            else
            {
                Device device = await registryManager.GetDeviceAsync(deviceID);
                if (device != null)
                {
                    string s_connectionStringNew = "*";
                    s_deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(s_connectionStringNew, Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.TransportType.Amqp);
                    s_deviceClient.OpenAsync();
                    string messageString = "";
                    messageString = jsonserv;
                    var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageString));
                    message.Properties.Add("southnorth_msgid", "com.intel.wsn.sensorData");
                    Task task = s_deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
                    await task;
                    s_deviceClient.CloseAsync();
                    await Task.Delay(10);
                }
                else
                {
                    device = await registryManager.AddDeviceAsync(new Device(deviceID));
                    string s_connectionStringNew = "*";
                    s_deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(s_connectionStringNew, Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.TransportType.Amqp);
                    string messageString = "";
                    messageString = jsonserv;
                    var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageString));
                    message.Properties.Add("southnorth_msgid", "com.intel.wsn.sensorData");
                    Task task = s_deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
                    await Task.Delay(1000 * 10);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("File Upload time end " + DateTime.Now);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not certain what the question is, but I do see some issues with the code you posted. You're not awaiting `s_deviceClient.OpenAsync()`, `s_deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message)` or `s_deviceClient.CloseAsync()`. The Task.Delay should not be necessary either. You might have added that to combat the side effect of your tasks not completing before moving on.

Comment: @Malathi the suggestions above helped you fix it?